# Spring.Net friendly state machine

Tags: c#, spring.net, state-machine

Is there a Spring.Net friendly state machine or Spring.Net friendly wrapper which is easy to configure using Spring.Net? (Delegates/Actions/Func aren't very nice to set using Spring.Net from my point of view...)